# CMake Error : Could NOT find PythonLibsUnix

Tags: linux, cmake, blender

I have the following problem when I try to compile [Blender](https://github.com/blender/blender):

```
Could NOT find PythonLibsUnix (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARY PYTHON_LIBPATH
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR)
```

OS : Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks.

Comment: From [this](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/error-building-fracture-branch/8181) forum, you might try running `make deps` inside the `blender-git/blender/` directory to populate the dependencies.

Comment: Did you follow the [buld instructions](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu) for your Ubuntu? Please answer this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

From [Building Blender on Ubuntu](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu)

To get the code first you run

```
mkdir ~/blender-git
cd ~/blender-git
git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git
```

And then you download the libraries. This is the missing PYTHON_LIBRARY that by default is looked into the directory above.

```
mkdir ~/blender-git/lib
cd ~/blender-git/lib
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64
```

After that you can build normally from the source directory

```
cd ~/blender-git/blender
make update
make
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on openSUSE tumbleweed. The error message is misleading, it actually requires a certain version of python, 3.9 in my case. I installed *python39-devel* package and the error went away.

Comment: For those for whom this doesn't work use install `python3.9-dev`

I've spent hours

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a hack and maybe not the best solution, but it worked for me.

I am going to assume you downloaded the precompiled libraries using

```
mkdir ~/blender-git/lib
cd ~/blender-git/lib
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64
```

All required libraries should be in that  blender-git/lib directory.

When running the make command, Cmake will automatically look for the libraries in the directory above. I created a symbolic link in the directory above that points to the lib folder:

```
 ~/blender-git$ cd ..
 ~/$ ln -s  blender-git/lib lib
```

Then running

```
~/$ cd blender-git 
~/blender-git$ make
```

should work, and will find all required libraries.

I'm sure there is a better way to point Cmake to the right folder, but this hack worked for me.

Comment: I guess the downvoter knows a better way to do the trick, which I'm pretty sure exists. I would like to know how to improve my hack.

Comment: nope, this did not work for me. still getting same error

Comment: It seems to me that there is an error with the paths, taked from the docs at https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu

The last step is 
```
cd ~/blender-git/blender
make update
make
```

which means the `make` command is run on the "blender" folder, not its parent  blender-git, which holds both `lib` and `blender` folders